# Filter an array of objects so that no 2 objects are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following array. If the `st` and the `ct` are the same then the objects are considered to be the same. for example the 1st and the 3rd object have the same st and ct so the 3rd should be ignored(filtered out) of the final array.  How do I filter this array so that no 2 objects are identical, preferably using the `array.filter` method? i have read the documentation I just dont get how to express what i want as the conditional for the filter function.

```
[{
  "st": "2012",
  "id": "43",
  "ct": "1",
  "sd": "2"
},
{
  "st": "2015",
  "id": "45",
  "ct": "2",
  "sd": "2"
},
{
  "st":"2015",
  "id": "45",
  "ct": "2",
  "sd": "1"
},]
```

Comment: This is a perfect use case for using `Array.prototype.filter`. Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? What didn't you understand or where are you having difficulties?

Comment: Also, where two objects have the same `st` and `ct` values, how do you decide which object to retain and which to remove? Keep the first found?

Comment: const array = <YOUR ARRAY OF OBJECTS>;
const keys = [];
const filtered = array.filter(obj => {
    let key = obj.st+"#"+obj.ct;
    return !keys.includes(key) && keys.push(key);
});'

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
let uniqueArray = array.filter((o, i, self) => {
    return self.findIndex(z => z.ct === o.ct && z.st === o.st) !== i;
});
```

Comment: Using .findIndex gives this quadratic complexity, it's not necessary to look at so many elements in each iteration of .filter()

Comment: Fair - altho unless this array is massive, it probably wont be too bad

Comment: Yeah it's a neat solution without helper variables, but truth is that .filter alone can't accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

```
var objects = [{
      "st":"2012",
      "id": "43",
      "ct": "1",
      "sd": "2"
    },
    {
      "st":"2015",
      "id": "453",
      "ct": "2",
      "sd": "2"
    },
    {
        "st":"2012", // this is a duplicate
        "ct":"1"
    }
];

// Using a Set to keep track of uniqueness avoids iterating through the
// entire array with methods like .findIndex()
var knownKeys = new Set();

var key;
var uniqueObjects = objects.filter(function(obj) {
    key = obj.st + obj.ct;
    return !knownKeys.has(key) && knownKeys.add(key);
});
```

Comment: key can be duplicate for two different objects in this case, you can create key like obj.st+"#"+obj.ct

Comment: @AjayKumar No that doesn't make a difference. If the `st` and `ct` properties (which are assumed to be strings) are equal, than their concatenation is also equal.

Comment: Approach should cover all cases always

Comment: @AjayKumar The approach does cover all cases, always. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: As we can see the object values, ct and st can be integer from server. that's it.

Comment: @AjayKumar As we can see the object values they are clearly strings. The original question wasn't about making the algorithm work with *different types*.

Comment: If you are wrong at some place, it’s not the insult to accepting the better approach. It is good for all programmers.